# How to charge a fee in ethereum smart contract transactions

Tags: web3js, fees

I need help on how to charge a transaction fee in ethereum smart contract using web3? Also which web3 API can be used to check the validation of enough gas on the frontend of smart contract?

Comment: You charge fee in the contract, what does web3 has to do with this???

Comment: In most cases, the needed gas price to pay and the gas limit would be automatically calculated for you by the web3 library and you wouldn't have to actively think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to estimate the fee of the transaction?

```
let gasPrice = new BigNumber(15).times(1000000000);
let gasLimit = new BigNumber(21000);
let estimateFee = new BigNumber(gasPrice.times(gasLimit)).dividedBy(1000000000000000000).toString();
```